# change cell value afterChange with or without setDataAtCell/getDataAtCell handsontable

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I am try to update the values of a cell beside the cell that have been edited manually. Up on doing the calculation I need to change the value of cell A2 for example.

Case Steps:
- Value of A1 is edited.
- Calculation is done in javascript at afterChange event.
- Now Update the value in A2 with the calculated value.

In my case *getDataAtCell* and *setDataAtCell* methods are not working.
i am getting the below error.

> Cannot read property 'getDataAtCell' of undefined
>
> Cannot read property 'setDataAtCell' of undefined

Please suggest how to get and set the values. Be it with getDataAtCell/setDataAtCell methods or without these.

Here is the code:

```
afterChange: function(changes, source) {
changes.forEach(function(change) {
var row = change[0];
var col = change[1];
var oldVal = change[2];
var newVal = change[3];
alert(row + "\n" + col + "\n" + oldVal + "\n" + newVal);
 /*get value at cell 1,1*/
      alert(hot.getDataAtCell(1,1));
      hot.setDataAtCell(row, col+1, 'Some new value');
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want someone to find out why you get this error, you have no choice but putting the whole definition of your HandsOnTable. What you provide in your question is not enough.

However, what I can do is giving you a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/o8yu2kkt/) of :

```
   getDataAtCell(row,col);
```

To at least find out what you did wrong in your table definition.

Note that I didn't include setDataAtCell directly in the afterChange event because it will create an infinite loop.

In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/a62hd9z4/), I prevent the infinie loop by stoping the change if you try to do your calcul out of the table, but try to modify a value of the first column and you will see what I'm talking about.

---

My suggestion to make that sort of calculation is to use your initial data (myData), or a copy (depending of your needs), to make your calculation and load the data again.

Let's say that when you modify a cell [row,col] with a new value, it will also modify the cell on the right [row,col+1] by adding the value you just entered in [row,col] with the present value of [row,col+1] :

```
afterChange: function(changes, source) {
  if(!changes) {
    return;
  }
  $.each(changes, function(index, element) {
    var row = element[0];
    var col = element[1];
    var oldVal = element[2];
    var newVal = element[3];
    if(col+1<hot.countCols()) {
      myData[row][col+1]=parseInt(myData[row][col+1])+parseInt(newVal);
      hot.loadData(myData);
    }
  });
}
```

See the full example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w4gjaw0z/).
You can notice that loading the table again will not trigger the event afterChange as above, thus, not do your calculation over and over because afterChange is triggered every time.

Comment: Thanks buddy. Your example helped me a lot.